# Direct Path Load of TimeStamp Data With SQL*LDR

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

The SQL-LDR documentation states that you need to do a convetional Path Load:

> When you want to apply SQL functions
>   to data fields. SQL functions are not
>   available during a direct path load

I have TimeStamp data stored in a CSV file that I'm loading with SQL-LDR by describing the fields as such:

```
STARTTIME       "To_TimeStamp(:STARTTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')",
COMPLETIONTIME  "To_TimeStamp(:COMPLETIONTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')"
```

So my question is: Can you load timestamp data without a function, or is it the case that you can not do a Direct Path Load when Loading TimeStamp data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of someone successfully direct loading timestamp data:
[`Loading Data (Part 4): sqlldr (direct, skip_index_maintainance)`](http://oracle-unix.blogspot.com/2007/07/loading-data-part-4-sqlldr-direct.html)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2661160) OTN Forum thread:

> you just need to set the environment
>   variable NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT to tell
>   SQL*Loader what format to expect the
>   timestamp to be in:
>
> set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH24:MI:SS.FF
>
> ..and remove the reference to the
>   to_timestamp function completely from
>   the controlfile.

Comment: Tried this, and got the following error:
ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error

Should this work on *nix systems in addition to windows?

Answer (score 0):

As a side note most of us have discontinued using “sql loader” for the more advance version “External Tables” assuming you’re on a newer version of Oracle.